# printf command not working after a specific point in my program

Tags: c, file, file-io, scanf, undefined-behavior

I'm working on a program with a 2D array of 365 data points, where one of the things we need to do is find the mean of the data and print it to a file and also to the command window.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

void main(void) {
  char Check[32] = {
    '\0'
  };
  FILE * F = NULL;
  FILE * R;
  int ** size;
  int x[500], y[500];

  //ERROR CHECK FOR FILE
  R = fopen("results.txt", "w");
  while (F == NULL) {
    printf("What is the name of the file?\n");
    scanf("%s", & Check);
    F = fopen(Check, "r");
    if (F == NULL) {
      printf("Error: file not found\n");
    }
  }
  //READ DATA FROM FILE
  for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    size = fscanf(F, "%d %d", & x[i], & y[i]);
    if (size == EOF) {
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Temperatures on Day %d in 1930 = %d \t 2001 = %d\n", i, x[i], y[i]);
      fprintf(R, "Temperatures on Day %d in 1930 = %d \t 2001 = %d\n", i, x[i], y[i]);
    }
  }
  fclose(R);
  printf("\n");
  //FIND MEAN OF DATA

  int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

  for (int f = 0; f <= 365; f++) {
    sum1 = sum1 + size[f][0];
    sum2 = sum2 + size[f][1];
  }
  double mean1 = (double) sum1 / 365;
  double mean2 = (double) sum2 / 365;

  //PRINT TO FILE
  FILE * L;
  L = fopen("results.txt", "a");
  printf("\nThe average temperature of 1930 is: %lf\nThe average temperature of 2001 is: %.4lf", mean1, mean2);
  fprintf(L, "\nThe average temperature of 1930 is: %lf\nThe average temperature of 2001 is: %.4lf", mean1, mean2);

}
```

However, I've built my code several times and when I run it the program won't print the mean to the command window. It just wont execute any code after that, and it also won't put the statement I want into the file I created. I've attached an image of what my program does when I run it, and it seems to run fine aside from a small delay after completing the loop for the data. I've tried to look for a solution online but nothing I find seems to help with my problem. I've rebuilt the program multiple times, and also have closed and launched Geany (the software I use) multiple times as well. If it helps, my code is saved on a .c file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzOkI.png)

Comment: `int ** size;` why is size a pointer to a pointer to int?  `sum1 = sum1 + size[f][0]` and what is that supposed to be doing? you read all your numbers into `x` and `y` but you don't calculate the sums based on them . `sum1 += x[f]` would make far more sense to me.  As it is I'd expect your program to generate a segmentation fault when you attempt to access `size[f][0]` since `size` is now set to the results of `EOF`.  your compiler (gcc?) should have warned you.  if your code generates warnings when compiled, you ned to fix them.

Comment: The image indicates that the OS is windows, so the compiler probably isn't gcc.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument expression of this call of scanf

```
scanf("%s", & Check);
```

has invalid type. Instead you need to write

```
scanf("%s", Check);
```

The valid range of indices for the arrays x and y declared like

```
int x[500], y[500];
```

is `[0, 500)`.

So this for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

The variable size declared as having a pointer type

```
int ** size;
```

So using it in these statements

```
size = fscanf(F, "%d %d", & x[i], & y[i]);
if (size == EOF) {
```

does not make sense. The return type of the function `fscanf` is `int`. The function is declared like

```
int fscanf(FILE * restrict stream, const char * restrict format, ..);
```

And  after the for loop the pointer will have the value EOF or the value 2 (provided that the code will be compiled). In this case these statements

```
for (int f = 0; f <= 365; f++) {
  sum1 = sum1 + size[f][0];
  sum2 = sum2 + size[f][1];
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: So then what should I do to fix these undefined behaviors? Because for my sum1=sum1+size[f][0] code that won't work unless I make the size variable a pointer

Comment: @RobertWestmeyer You read data in the arrays x and y. You need to use them in this for loop   for (int f = 0; f <= 365; f++) {
    sum1 = sum1 + size[f][0];
    sum2 = sum2 + size[f][1];
  } instead of the variable size. Using the pointer size does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to follow the usage of `size`. It's declared as `int **`, however, the assignment is `size = fscanf(F, "%d %d", & x[i], & y[i]);`. Then `size` should be `EOF` after the first for loop is over. Then dereference  it in the second for loop will cause undefined behaviour which abort the program.
It seems to me that you should use array `x[]` and `y[]` to compute the mean.
Moreover, the first loop is [1..500], the second one is [0..365], even you use `x[]` and `y[]` to compute the mean, because both arrays aren't initialised, access `x[0]` and `y[0]` will yield garbage value, resulting in wrong result.